# How to collect rows by string pattern in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, pattern-matching

I have a table with Products and Sales, and I want to show them putting together the products with similar name and sorting by Sales. This is the initial table:

```
Product             Sales
Shirt (blue)         10
Trainers (orange)     1
Shirt (green)         2
Hooding (yellow)      7
```

To put them together would be used a pattern that take what is outside parentheses. The result would be like this:

```
Product             Sales
Shirt (blue)         10
Shirt (green)         2
Hooding               7
Trainers (orange)     1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "collecting the names of the products?" Is there one table for Products and one for Sales, or are they in one table?

Comment: @Mifeet Looks like they need to be 'grouped' (just put rows next to one other, not `GROUP BY`) (i.e. the two `Shirt` entries are in consecutive rows).

Comment: Yes, is like Dukeling says. Put them together but not grouping.

Comment: If that's the case, wouldn't  `ORDER BY product, sales DESC` be enough?

Comment: No Mifeet, because i want to show as first the best seller and then the 'similar' products, and then another time the second best seller...

Comment: And does it need to be one query? I would retrieve best sellers first and similar products in another query. Btw, an explicit link between related products would be really useful, you never know when your customer will want more complex related products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a derived table:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table1 a
JOIN (SELECT MID(Product, 1, LOCATE('(', Product)-1) substrProduct,
             SUM(Sales) salesSum
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY substrProduct) b
  ON MID(a.Product, 1, LOCATE('(', a.Product)-1) = b.substrProduct
ORDER BY b.salesSum desc, a.sales desc
```

[Test](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f63eb3/8).

I'll leave it to you to figure out what's going on there. See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) for details on `MID` and `LOCATE`.